# Facebook app not in showing in search: Over 10 MAU, Sandbox mode disabled

Tags: facebook, search

I developed a Facebook app for my company.  My app has over 10 monthly users, so I thought this was just a delay with FB rebuilding their search index.  However, my app went live in February, and it still doesn't show up in the search.  People can, however, play the game by using the canvas URL.

Also, users who have already added my app can find it in the FB search, just not any new players.

Sandbox mode is disabled.

Is there another setting somewhere that I need to change in order to make the app searchable?

Any other suggestions?  I'm all Googled out.  :(

Comment: What's your application name (Namespace)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app needs to have had over 10 MAU for between 2 and 4 weeks before the search index is rebuilt to include your app; this is mentioned on the [main Apps on Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#search):

> When your App reaches 10 monthly active users it will be automatically queued to be included in the search index the next time we rebuild our search index (we rebuild every 2-4 weeks). After the index is rebuilt your app will be discoverable via Search.

Comment: Thanks, Igy.  I've already read that part of the FB documentation.  My app satisfies both requirements (3587 MAU, released 7 weeks ago), however it is still not indexed.  (Sandbox Mode is also disabled.)  I was wondering if I missed something else on my end before I try to contact FB, directly.  Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I know, no; most common reason have for this problem is that the 2-4 weeks starts after the 10MAU count is hit, not when the app is created, so that can add unexpected delays

Comment: Thanks.  Maybe the 2-4 weeks started March 1, then.  I'll give it another week or two before I contact FB directly.